# Will Kubuntu 12.04 run on 256 MB Ram?

Tags: kubuntu, ram

For two weeks, I have been trying to install Kubuntu 12.04.1 onto a Kingston USB stick to run on my Acer Aspire 1362 Laptop, which has 256MB RAM.

Firstly I downloaded: kubuntu-2.04.1-desktop-i386.iso from the GetKubuntu website.

To install it on the USB I tried Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.1.1.exe from PendriveLinux website. This didn't work completely so I tried  LinuxLive USB Creator 2.8.16.exe from the Linux live website.  In both cases I received a message indicating a successful installation and the USB was clearly trying to boot to Kububtu, but failed to get as far as the login screen.

In searching web resources I have found a suggestion that Kubuntu is happier with at least 512MB RAM, but will run (albeit slowly) on as little as 256. Can anyone help on this, please? Has anyone successfully installed Kubuntu on  laptop with so little memory – if so how and what version of Kubuntu? - or should I try another Linux?

Comment: Why edit a 9 year old question about an Ubuntu version that's been EOL for 4 or 6 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As on [Wikipedia: Kubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu), you need 384MB RAM for minimum requirements. If you still install it on your laptop, it can't works.

Why you didn't try the other derivative of Ubuntu like Xubuntu or Lubuntu? Two of them works on smaller RAM. (Note: Xubuntu 12.04 minimum requirements is 512MB, but Xubuntu 11.04 or 10.04 needs 256MB to works)